# JSON from Nextcloud not accepted in Fullcalender.io

Tags: json, fullcalendar, icalendar, nextcloud

We store events in a Nextcloud-calender. When I download that as a .ics-File and convert it using ical2json I get this:

```
    {
              "CATEGORIES": "2 Konferenzen/Dienstbesprechungen/Zeugnisse/Versetzung",
              "CLASS": "PUBLIC",
              "CREATED": "20191121T124806Z",
              "DESCRIPTION": "\\n",
              "DTEND;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"": "20200310T180000",
              "DTSTAMP": "20200423T154025Z",
              "DTSTART;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"": "20200310T161500",
              "LAST-MODIFIED": "20200310T185528Z",
              "PRIORITY": "5",
              "SEQUENCE": "0",
              "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=de": "Ausschuss \"Demokratiebildung\"",
              "TRANSP": "OPAQUE",
              "UID": "AAAAAB8xF0n+5WRAjtK1pGHynwKkVWYB",
              "X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html": "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E",
              "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS": "BUSY",
              "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE": "1",
              "X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER": "FALSE",
              "X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE": "0"
            },
            {
              "CATEGORIES": "2 Konferenzen/Dienstbesprechungen/Zeugnisse/Versetzung",
              "CLASS": "PUBLIC",
              "CREATED": "20191121T124842Z",
              "DESCRIPTION": "\\n",
              "DTEND;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"": "20200113T180000",
              "DTSTAMP": "20200423T154025Z",
              "DTSTART;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"": "20200113T161500",
              "LAST-MODIFIED": "20200114T063102Z",
              "PRIORITY": "5",
              "SEQUENCE": "0",
              "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=de": "Ausschuss \"Demokratiebildung\"",
              "TRANSP": "OPAQUE",
              "UID": "AAAAAB8xF0n+5WRAjtK1pGHynwIEVmYB",
              "X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html": "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E",
              "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS": "BUSY",
              "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE": "1",
              "X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER": "FALSE",
              "X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE": "0"
            }
```

According to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ this is valid JSON (RFC 8259).

FullCalender.io doesn't work with this as it expects something like this:

```
   {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2020-04-12T14:30:00'
    },
```

Do you have any suggestions what I can do now? I don't find a way to convert my .ics-fil to JSON, that is accepted by FullCalender.io. I am really lost here...

Comment: by the way, this is the original iCalender-Code (shortend a bit:

`BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:2 Konferenzen/Dienstbesprechungen/Zeugnisse/Versetzung
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20190923T073128Z
DESCRIPTION:\n
DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20191104T183000
DTSTAMP:20200423T154025Z
DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20191104T161500
LAST-MODIFIED:20191104T180345Z
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=de:Ausschuss: Demokratiebildung 
END:VEVENT`

Comment: you can just write some Javascript to collect the properties you want from the first object and output a new object with new property names for those values. If you are giving the URL of the JSON file directly to fullCalendar in the `events` setting, you can use the [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) callback for this purpose. Or you can use the [events-as-a-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) design pattern to give you a place in the code to do the task.